# MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP for PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, timestamp

Basically I am trying to convert a date field from my database into a number of seconds old. I used UNIX_TIMESTAMP on our old MySQL database and am looking for an equivalent function in PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM your_datetime_column)
FROM your_table
```

More details in the manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '1970-01-01';
```

Will give you an `interval` type. You can get seconds out of that interval result if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to convince existing MySQL queries to work, this is what I have, seem to be working fine to me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_field timestamp with time zone) RETURNS integer 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN extract(epoch FROM date_field);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```