# SQLAlchemy group by interval 30 mins

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am pretty new in Python and SQL Alchemy and I have a question about a query that I am trying to do.

More specifically I have this data list. It contains some measures every 5 mins. 
What I would like to do is to group by timestamp, based on 30 mins, so when:

- 00:15:00+00 -> 00:00:00+00
- 00:20:00+00 -> 00:00:00+00
- 00:30:00+00 -> 00:30:00+00
- 00:35:00+00 -> 00:30:00+00
- etc

and then aggregate the data on that value.

Now I have the code below:

```
base_query = (
        db.query(
            MyTable.timestamp,
            func.max(MyTable.dual).label("max"),
            func.min(MyTable.dual).label("min"),
            func.avg(MyTable.dual).label("avg"),
            func.count(MyTable.id).label("count"),
        )
        .join(Simulation, Simulation.id == MyTable.simulation_id)
        .filter(
            and_(MyTable.dual > 0, Simulation.scenario_id == scenario_id)
        )
        .group_by(MyTable.timestamp)
        .order_by(MyTable.timestamp)
    )
```

```
timestamp                   count   avg
"2020-01-13 00:00:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:05:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:10:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:15:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:20:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:25:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:30:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:35:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:40:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:45:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:50:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 00:55:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 01:00:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 01:05:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 01:10:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
"2020-01-13 01:15:00+00"    "10"    "6454.70683325249"
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Postgres. Sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: You might find these useful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57582/group-by-timestamp-interval-10-minutes-postgresql, https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.BSF.4.10.10007192254020.9376-100000@maximillion.sscsinc.com.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345308/5320906) that uses postgres' interval feature

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, we must figure out how to do it in sql. Getting half an hour intervals
should not be too difficult:

```
select 1800*(floor(unix_timestamp(timestamp)/1800))
```

You might want convert this back to datetime, but I am afraid that's not 
portable enough. In mysql you can use from_unixtime, but if you get the
unix timestamp as the result of the query, you can easily convert it to
anything you want in python.

Secondly, how to do it in sqlalchemy. It looks like it is pretty 
straightforward:

```
 import sqlalchemy
 from sqlalchemy import select, func
 q = select([
    (1800*func.floor(func.unix_timestamp(t.c.tm0)/1800)).label("tm_hh") 
 ]))
 print(q)
 # prints out this:
 # SELECT %s * floor(unix_timestamp(T.tm0) / %s) AS tm_hh \nFROM T
```

Comment: I am getting this error
`ERROR:  function unix_timestamp(timestamp with time zone) does not exist`

Comment: Right, I thought unix_timestamp is a standard sql function. For postgress this might work: SELECT extract(epoch FROM your_datetime_column)
FROM your_table (via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857990/mysql-unix-timestamp-for-postgresql)